# Go to next screen not working when i am using from function

Tags: react-native

React Native, I am trying to push from one screen to the second screen on the button Press.Code is working when I am call `on press` , but it's not working when I have created one function and try to push the second screen. give me the error.

```
 <Button
                    title="Go to Details"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', {
                        name: 'John',
                        age: 12,
                    })}
                    // onPress={gotoSecondButton}

gotoSecondButton = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', {
        name: 'John',
        age: 12,
    })
}
```

I have comment one code it's not working. I have to show the second view controller from the function. Because I have to use validation on this function.

```
onPress={gotoSecondButton}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have binding problems. React Native does not know what **this** is refering to in gotoSecondButton function. The solution is to bind gotoSecondButton in constructor, like this :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.gotoSecondButton = this.gotoSecondButton.bind(this);
}
```